# How to implement Apache Rewrite Rule correctly?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Following is my rewrite rule code written in the .htaccess file placed in the

> beta1

folder.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /beta1/
RewriteRule /(.*) read.php?post=$1 [R,NC]
```

Currently the URL is:

> http://localhost/beta1/read.php?post=Happy+Mother+Day.

And i want the link to appear like:

> http://localhost/beta1/Happy-Mother-Day.

Do I also need to change the way "read.php" extracts data from the database? If yes, then how?
Do i also need to make any changes in the "read.php" file?

The rewrite code above is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey please try this rule

```
 RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

 RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?$    read.php?post=$1    [NC,L]
```

And read.php file

```
  echo str_replace('-',' ', $_GET['post']);
```

Comment: How to check if the modification is working or not? And do i also need to change/add anything in read.php?

Comment: you replace this code by your code in .htaccess file. and in read.php file you have to get the $_GET data.

Comment: do you check the http://localhost/beta1/Happy-Mother-Day and do you get result form the read.php file?

Comment: I get the title of the post with $_GET['post']; then sanitize it and then retrieve data from mysql.

Comment: please add your question with code of read.php file what you want.

Comment: yes it is solved. but i'm unable to get the data of the variable in my read.php.

Comment: I want to get the data of post= as $_GET['post'] but i'm getting it with hyphens.

Comment: post = explode('/', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
 echo $_GET['post'] = $post[3];
 //$title=@filter_var($_GET['post'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
 $post=@urldecode($post[3]); 
 echo $post = addslashes($post);

I want the value of $post in the end as "Happy Mother Day." without quotes.

Comment: okay you simple use this function $data =  str_replace('-',' ',$_GET['post']);